# Частично не работает свойство perspective

Tags: css, firefox, hover

Недавно захотелось поработать с 3d в браузере, когда я начал работу, то поянл, что в браузере Mozila Firefox у меня подвисает свойство perspective, то есть если я ставил изначально у элемента transform: rotateX(odeg), предположим, а на hover ставил, к примеру, 50deg, то у меня очень сильно подвисал сам блок, потом запустил этот же сайт с opera и все работало отлично, с чем может быть связана данная проблема?? Заранее спасибо!

p.s. пробовал префиксы для браузеры, все равно не работает

вот ссылка на видео с проблемой https://youtu.be/Wa-2_Riap74

фрагмент кода

css

```
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 0px;
}
.card-box{
    perspective: 1000px;
-moz-perspective: 1000px;
-moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
transform: perspective(1000px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card{
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

js

```
var card = document.getElementsByClassName('card')[0];

var height = card.offsetHeight /2;
var width = card.offsetWidth /2;

card.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var x = e.offsetX;
    var y = e.offsetY;

    console.log(-(x - width)/5);

    card.style.transform = ' rotateY('+-(x - width)/5+'deg)';
    console.log(x);

});
```

также вот ссылка на сайт, залил на свой хост, чтобы вы поняли hostzadoroshniya.ru/trouble_perspective

Comment: Воспроизводимый пример кода приведите

Comment: https://youtu.be/Wa-2_Riap74

Answer (score 0):

свойтсво `transform-style: preserve-3d;` надо применять к родительскому элементу, а не к дочернему.